# How do I do anonymous Firebase logins which allow browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I'm doing a javascript single-page app which allows people to log in, either via twitter or (for some use cases) anonymously.

A very important thing to figure out was how to let them reload the page -- this shouldn't force them to log back in!

I figured this out pretty quickly for the twitter login, and so it uses cookie-stored information to log back in (specifically, the user_id, oauth_token and oauth_token_secret).

However, I can't seem to make this work with the anonymous login facility.

I tried:

```
auth.login("anonymous", {
  user_id: @get("userId"),
  firebase_auth_token: @get("firebaseAuthToken")
});
```

but it doesn't work... I get a new anonymous user ID.  I want to keep the same one for the duration of the user's browser session.

And yeah, I tried both `user_id` and `id`, `firebaseAuthToken` and `firebase_auth_token`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, sessions are created any time you successfully log in a user, and last up until the session expiration time configured under the 'Auth' tab in Forge. This built-in sessioning applies to all Simple Login authentication types, and is automatic as long as local storage and cookies are available.

To resume a session, simply instantiate the `FirebaseSimpleLogin` object with a Firebase reference and callback. If a local session exists, the callback will be invoked with the same payload you would see if you had just logged the user in for the first time. Invoking the `login` method will always generate a brand new auth. flow regardless of current user authentication state or session.

Note that in anonymous auth, once a user session expires it cannot be recovered. This may change in the future or some additional functionality may be added to enable it, but it is currently only logged-in to once per user id.